# Bash / exit status is 0, while expected is 255

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Have a code I've used for the tests

`hola="cd /var && ssh localhost.error"
$hola
echo $?`

Executing just

`cd /var && ssh localhost.error`

will return code 255.

But executing

`hola="cd /var && ssh localhost.error"
$hola`

returns 0, while expected 255.

`hola="ssh localhost.error"
$hola`

returns 255.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hola="cd /var && ssh localhost.error"
$hola
```

When you do this, the second line causes you to invoke the `cd` command with the arguments `/var`, `&&`, `ssh`, and `localhost.error`. Cd ignores everything but the first argument, and it successfully changes to /var, so it doesn't print an error.

This happens because of the order in which bash processes command lines. When you type `cd /var && ssh localhost.error`, this in bash terms is a **list** of two **command**s. Bash parses lists into their separate commands, then parses each command. Variable expansion occurs during command parsing, not list parsing.

When you run `$hola`, the list parser parses it as a single command. the command parser runs, expands the variable, and sees the &&, but it's not special to the command parser.

You could try using a shell function instead:

```
function hola { cd /var && ssh localhost.error; }
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I get commands as strings. And I figured out that there is ```eval``` ... and it works like a charm :)

```eval $hola```

Thanks for explanation about the string thing :)

Comment: Gah, please don't use `eval`, you'll just make subtler and weirder bugs. Functions are a much better way to do this sort of thing. See [BashFAQ #40](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the fact that you are not running the command in the same line, but saving the string with the command and then calling the variable holding that string.

Try this instead:

```
hola=$(cd /var && ssh localhost.error)
echo $hola
```

That should return `255`, or whatever error code you are expecting.

Look at this example:

```
> hola="echo hi"
> $hola
hi
>echo $?
0

> hola="hi"
> $hola
ksh: hi:  not found
> echo $?
127
```

Comment: 127 is a different error - file not found. I had to use ```eval```